# Is Demon: the Descent playable with 1e nWoD rules?

Tags: house-rules, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Can you play D:tD with the 1e nWoD rules? Can you simply remove the expanded GMC rules and just run it like, say, Hunter: the Vigil? What other modifications would be necessary, and what should I look out for?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, but it's not intended to done**

To be pedantic, almost anything can be adapted into CoD / 1e nWoD; the number of fan-made and homebrew supplements that can be found attest to that. And, full disclaimer, while I recently ran a CtL/HtV game that had a handful of Demon characters, they were all NPCs - so that's what my experience is based off of.

Assuming you have the DtD core also means you have its appendix, which helps to convert from 1st to 2nd ed; so it's not too difficult to convert entities that haven't crossed into 2nd ed - Hunters, Mummies, etc.

But, assuming this would be more work/not desired, it is entirely feasible to take a Demon character sheet to a 1st ed game and successfully engage. Playing a Demon character over the course of a chronicle has some potential pitfalls:

- The XP system is completely different between editions

For example, 2nd ed uses Beats, which are more representative of "adversity encountered". In addition, most creature types can earn a special variant of Beats that allow them to progress faster/differently than regular Beats: in the case of Demons, they can gain Cover Beats, which allow their covers to more starkly diverge.

So, it may be difficult to decide on fair prices for Demon traits.

- Different Willpower economy

Willpower is meant to be a more liquid asset in 2nd ed; easier to earn, more enticing to spend. To stick closer towards a 1st ed Willpower economy would hamper Demons, but it's difficult to remove some of the Willpower costs without drastically increasing their power.

- Power creep

It's natural for progressive editions to increase the "power levels" of the various playable creatures; to make them more enticing and just show off new tricks. DtD, debuting for 2nd ed, implies an "un-creeped" 1st ed, with Demons a little less powerful.

This is very context dependent, though; a troupe of half Mages, half Demons could still feel on even footing, but a Demon in a Hunter cell would have an undisputed advantage. All creatures aren't made equally, and mostly power balance among themselves; but, in a mixed troupe, it's worth consideration for balance of agency.

YMMV for your own troupe.

- Combat is overhauled in the 2nd ed

This shouldn't be a major problem (eg, it's harder to get hit with lethal in 1st ed), but should be something to watch out for; a player used to 2nd ed might request "down and dirty combat", which wouldn't make sense to a 1st ed only ST.

- Morality / ethics revision

For Virtues and Vices, Demons have pretty wide choices. It may be easy to translate a Vice of "Overconfidence" into "Pride", but figuring out what Virtue should be used in place of "Obtuseness" is not as trivial.

Morality for Demons is the integrity of their Cover(s). Again, this involves more to keep track of, and the Breaking Points for each Cover can vary as well.

---

Again, there may be other trouble spots, and I'm fully aware I haven't given any concrete advice; but, in my opinion, these are the key places to form the house rules that would allow a troupe to have Demon PC(s) in a 1st ed setting while still having fun.